# why my google dfp(Double Click) can not create mobile ad unit?

Tags: double-click, google-dfp

[image]

I want to create an ad unit to display at mobile devices.After i clicked add ad unit button, i can not find the way to create mobile ad unit.

In the tutorial of offical google dfp ,i've found there's an arrow right aside of the add ad unit button. it's not displayed in my browser.
see my picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is an old tutorial. DFP recently changed so that there is now only one type of ad unit and it detects whether to serve a mobile or desktop ad automatically.

You can read more about this here: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3235135